# Python pattern matching: Not able to understand the reason

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

What am I doing wrong ?

```
Input file data format : 
 Address: data modified         Phone: 7373737373
    Eligibility:                                    Age: 12
                                                    Sex: MALE
           Race:                                         

#Test file
content = open("output.txt","r")

# Output file
fileCSV = open("testCSV.csv","a")

patAddress = re.compile('Address:[\w \W \S \d \D - / + ,  = \s ]{40}')
patAge = re.compile('Age:[0-9 \s]{1,3}')
patSex = re.compile('Sex:[a-z A-Z \s \S]{1,2}')
for value in content:
    address = patAddress.findall(value)
    sex = patSex.findall(value)
    age = patAge.findall(value)
    for p_address in address:
        fileCSV.write(p_address)
    for p_sex in sex:
        fileCSV.write("|"+p_sex)
    for p_age in age:
        fileCSV.write("|"+p_age)
        fileCSV.write("\n")
fileCSV.close();
```

I wanted output to be something like this :

```
Address : some text| Sex: M|Age: 25 \n in the end
```

I am getting output as:

```
Address : some text|Age: 25 
|Sex: M
```

This is the exact output I am getting an \n after the Sex as well.

Can anyone tell me the reason behind this. This is 3rd day with python, I mean I am new to python. I am not able to get the reason behind printing the Age before Sex

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you show your sample input?

Comment: This much only I can share, That output.txt is file with lots of data. I need to convert it to csv(only required fields).

Answer (score 0):

You should probably move the block of code that writes the output:

```
for p_address in address:
    fileCSV.write(p_address)
for p_sex in sex:
    fileCSV.write("|"+p_sex)
for p_age in age:
    fileCSV.write("|"+p_age)
    fileCSV.write("\n")
```

out of the

```
for value in content:
```

loop.

Right now, it prints those as they are found in the input, not in the order you are trying to write them.

---- EDIT ---- (after comments, to handle multiple values)

Here is some code:

```
address_list=[]
sex_list=[]
age_list=[]
for value in content:
    address = patAddress.findall(value)
    address_list.extend(address)
    sex = patSex.findall(value)
    sex_list.extend(sex)
    age = patAge.findall(value)
    age_list.extend(age)

for p_address in address_list:
    fileCSV.write(p_address)
for p_sex in sex_list:
    fileCSV.write("|"+p_sex)
for p_age in age_list:
    fileCSV.write("|"+p_age)

fileCSV.write("\n")
fileCSV.close();
```

Comment: Then when you find an address, sex or age, you should add them to a list in that 'for value in content:' loop. And only after you should print those.

Comment: Can you be more clear?. There are chances that number of address ,age and sex maybe unequal[This is my point of view I don't know the OP's full data] ?

Comment: If I move out of the content then how can I parse the file having multiple values containing the same pattern. It needs to be broken as individual data. That file has multiple occurrence for Sex age and address field, but once for each unique ID.

Comment: You make separate lists for each (address, sex, age), initialize them with address_list = [], sex_list = [], age_list=[] and when you run the regular expressions, do address_list.extend(address) and so on. Then print from those lists.

Comment: Now what if the file size is more then 5 gb? If I create a variable then how much will be the array size ?

Comment: If your input is that big, I imagine this is not for only one person and you'll need more code to determine when it goes from one individual to the next (and print that \n)

Comment: Now as per your program output will look something like `address1,address2....addressn|sex1|sex2....|sexn|age1|age2...|agen` and not like `address1|sex1|age1\naddress2|sex2|age2etc..`

Comment: As I said, with the written format ( I was using ) I was able to get the format as required, but it will be totally unpredictable.

Comment: Could it be possible to chat instead of commenting here?

Answer (score 0):

> I am getting output as:
>
> ```
> Address : some text|Age: 25 
> |Sex: M
> ```
>
> This is the exact output I am getting an \n after the Sex as well.
>
> Can anyone tell me the reason behind this.

It is simply because in the loop

```
    for p_age in age:
        fileCSV.write("|"+p_age)
        fileCSV.write("\n")
```

a `"\n"` is written after *each* `"|"+p_age`.

There are other problems with the code. I suggest:

```
…
for value in iter(content.readline, ''):
    address = patAddress.search(value)
    if address:
        age = patAge.search(content.readline())
        sex = patSex.search(content.readline())
        fileCSV.write(address.group()+"|"+sex.group()+"|"+age.group()+"\n")
fileCSV.close()
```